# Encapsulation and passing primitives to methods

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have questions regarding encapsulation rules and difference between next two classes

```
class Phone { 
    public String model; 
    double weight; 
    public void setWeight(double w){
        weight = w;
    }
    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
}

class Home {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phone ph = new Phone();
        ph.setWeight(12.23);
        System.out.println(ph.getWeight());
    }
}
```

In the book for Java for I OCA certification this is example of well encapsulated class
and from set and get method we can access weight variable and pritns 12.23.

but what confused me is next class:

```
class Employee { 
    int age; 
    void modifyVal(int age) {  // even if parameter is d instead age prints the same
        age = age + 1;        // even if parameter is d instead age prints the same
        System.out.println(age); 
    }
}

class Office {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Employee e = new Employee();
        System.out.println(e.age);
        e.modifyVal(e.age);
        System.out.println(e.age);
    }
}
```

It print:
010

meaning that method modifyVal cannot access age variable. Can somebody explain  why variable havent change after applying the modufyVal method and what is the difference?

Comment: It would be a *lot* easier to read your post if you'd format your code cleanly.

Comment: It's not clear what you want `modifyVal` to do. If you call `e.modifyVal(10); e.modifyVal(20);` what should the result be?

Comment: What is not clear for me is difference between this two methods (setWeight and modifyVal), why after printing first method change variable and second not?

Comment: As has been explained in the answers, you're setting the `age` parameter, not the `age` field. Compare that with `setWeight` where you have a parameter name which is different to the field name.

Comment: even when I change age parameter to something else it print the same. I am still beginner with Java

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you mean by "change age parameter to something else" - you'd need to give a complete example, showing exactly what you've tried and what the result was.

Comment: if I change age parameter to be diferent than age field I am getting the same results. And I still dont understand the difference between setWeight and modifyVal methods

Comment: Repeat the same description rather than showing a complete example doesn't really help.

Comment: Jakub Hr helped me to understand this. Anyway than you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
age = age + 1; //it's overwriting age parameter and not accessing age instance variable
```

If it was like that it would modify the `age` instance variable

```
this.age = age + 1;
```

Comment: This is example from the book, I just copy it.

Comment: Ok, so only first part is important for you. I'll remove the second part.

Comment: What is not clear for me is difference between this two methods (setWeight and modifyVal), why after printing first method change variable and second not? thats why I put this two examples

Comment: in setWeight method instance variable is called weight and parameter of the method is called w, so there is no name conflict because weight and w names are different. In modifyVal name of instance variable is the same as the name of the parameter which is age and because of that there is name conflict and modifyVal method operates only on parameter age variable. It's because of variable scopes in Java.

Comment: if I change age parameter to d it print the same

Comment: if you change only `void modifyVal(int age)` to `void modifyVal(int d)` the result is 011, for sure.

Comment: I just did it in eclipse and it prints 010

Comment: So you'are doing something wrong. Have a look here http://ideone.com/Tkr51h that's your code with age parameter changed to d and the output is 0 1 1

Comment: Yes I found mistake, you are right I now understand. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `modifyVal` method, the operations on `age` are scoped to the `age` argument of the method, never to `this.age` of the class instance.

Therefore `this.age` is not incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
age = age + 1;
```

must be

```
this.age = age + 1;
```

When the instance variable and the method variable have the same name you have to tell java which one you are manipulating.  In absence of `this` it will take the method variable hence you should use `this.age`.

Comment: but why weight is not this.weight

Comment: @hpko - because there is a difference in variable names "w" and "weight". The compiler sees it. The "local" field is not shadowing the "instance level field"

Comment: The variable has a different name.  When your instance variable has the same name as the parameter in you have to declare which one you want to manipulate.

Comment: that is clear but look at setWeight and modifyVal methods and can you tell me difference? except public access modifiers

Comment: the name of the variables are different in the setWeight method.  Because of this it is 100% clear for java which variable it is manipulating.

Answer (score 0):

```
 void modifyVal(int age) { 
 age = age + 1;            // not modifying age field of Employee class. local age field being passed to the function is being changed.
 System.out.println(age); 
 }


 System.out.println(e.age); // 0 : default value
 e.modifyVal(e.age);         // 1 : as  age = age + 1; i.e, 0+1
 System.out.println(e.age);  // 0 : default value
```